How to detect duplicate Job add in Bull Queue in Nest?
I am using bull queue in Nest. I know it adds only jobs with unique ids and if the job exists with that id, it doesn't add it and returns the existing job. Is there any way to check whether the job I added was actually added or ignored because it already existed? It doesn't even throw an error for duplicate IDs, so I can't tell.
const job = await this.sglQueue.add(jobName, jobData, {
    delay: (jobDelay * 1000),
    timeout: (jobTimeout * 1000),
    lifo: jobLIFO,
    removeOnFail: false,
    removeOnComplete: true,
    jobId: jobId, 
});


Interesting, maybe you can do queue.getJob(jobId)
after adding it to queue and if nothing is found then you can be certain that job wasn't added.

You didn't understand my question. I wanted to detect if a job with same id is already add or not.

Okay, can't you use the same function for that purpose as well ?
queue.getJob(jobId)
If it returns null , job with that id isn't added

Yes, I had added a if condition before adding a job (to check if job already exists), but the issue was that my code was multi-threaded and this condition was returning no jobs at that time.
